# Dynamics 365 Report Authoring Extension Crashes Visual Studio 2015

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2015, ssrs-2012, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2016

After installing the Dynamics CRM Report Authoring Extension [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50375), both Visual Studio 2015 and SQL Server Data Tools 2015 crash on startup, occassionally immediately after the splash-screen but usually after the UI loads.

If I uninstall the extension and run the command `devenv.exe /resetsettings` I can get Visual Studio to stop crashing, but obviously can't develop my reports.

I've already reinstalled VS and rebooted. How do I get past this?

EDIT:

I recreated the problem on another machine. Here's the steps to reproduce, be careful though since even reinstalls aren't fixing this:

- Install VS 2015
- Install SSDT 2015
- Attempt to Install Report Authoring Extension 2015. Install should fail.
- Attempt to Install 2016 Report Authoring Extension. Install should fail.
- Follow the steps [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2988630/fatal-error-during-installation-of-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2013-report-authoring-extensions) to fix the registry.
- Reinstall the 2016 Report Authoring Extension

Now Visual Studio should crash on startup

EDIT 2:

After reinstalling Windows I've hit the same problem. Visual Studio 2015 Professional. This time the only thing I did was install the 2016 Report Authoring Extension and Visual Studio crashes on startup. I uninstalled the extension but the problem is still happening.

Comment: I solved this issue by installing the **Azure SDK**.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you close the visual studio before doing this step.

Try to delete the ComponentModelCache folder in the C:\Users[username]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ComponentModelCache

Then Open the Visual Studio

This step works for me.

Comment: For my case

I install VS 2015,
I install Microsoft SSDT 2015,
I install Microsoft server 2012 express,
Then reboot the pc,
I install the Windows authoring 2016,
Then reboot the pc,

When the visual studio crashes after this installation i deleted the ComponentModelCache

Answer (score 1):

I was also having this issue and multiple repairs did not help.
I ended up having to uninstall the CRM Report Authoring extension, SSDT, and Visual Studio.  Then I did a clean install of Visual Studio 2015.  Afterwards I updated all extensions, including SSDT (you should be able to see all available updates in the notifications icon at the top of the screen). After everything was updated, I was able to re-install the Dynamics CRM Report Authoring Extension and so far everything has been working.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete folder ComponentModelCache from:

```
C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache
```

and restart Visual Studio.

OR/AND

Open Windows Registry:

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Components\0EF1E6B4EFCDA2649B26A424D56DAACD
```

If there you have two paths delete both. Then reinstall Dynamics CRM Report Authoring Extension and go to Step 1.

Comment: No luck with this. Still the same problems

Comment: @CamJohnson26 try to delete Dynamics CRM Report Authoring Extension and check VS after that. I have the same problem, VS crash on startup. Reinstall help me just for first startup VS, for second - the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had to re-install the Microsoft Online Services Sign-In Assistant ([link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=28177)).
After removing/re-installing that (repair on it was failing for me). It successfully installed.

It still did not work after that though so I tried Bryan Oab's suggestion to delete the ComponentModelCache and I was back in business.

Comment: Actually it seems I keep having to delete the ComponentCache folder over and over. A more complete answer would be greatly appreciated if anyone else has found something.